# convert array to object in vue js and return a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, variables, arraylist

i wanna ask my case about array and object, i still less of knowledge about this because still newbie. i have bunch of data as following:

```
    counterTraffic : [
    {
      id: 1,
      daerah: "Bandung",
      date:"1668790800000",
      kendaraan: [
        {rodaEmpat: 50},
        {rodaDua: 22},
        {truck: 30},
        {Bus: 70},
      ]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      daerah: "Tasik",
      date:"1668877200000",
      kendaraan: [
        {rodaEmpat: 80},
        {rodaDua: 15},
        {truck: 10},
        {Bus: 50},
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      daerah: "Bekasi",
      date:"1669050000000",
      kendaraan: [
        {rodaEmpat: 30},
        {rodaDua: 65},
        {truck: 20},
        {Bus: 100},
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      id: 4,
      daerah: "Bandung",
      date:"1668963600000",
      kendaraan: [
        {rodaEmpat: 20},
        {rodaDua: 15},
        {truck: 5},
        {Bus: 150},
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and i want take value data of counterTraffic.kendaraan and assign to new variable.
so when i go mapping the counterTraffic, and then assign to new variable with kendaraan data

```
the result have to become: let kendaraanNew = [50,22,30,70]
```

the data above from counterTraffic[0].kendaraan that already mapping before.

thank you for your helping

Comment: `[50,22,30,70]` Where do these numbers come from in your objects?

Comment: `let kendaraanNew = counterTraffic.map( (item) => { return item["kendaraan"][0]["rodaEmpat"]; });` ?

Comment: sorry my question not clear, so i want to create new variable kendaraanNew from counterTraffic that already mapping

Comment: @irahama I added an answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a funciton like below:

```
function getKendaraan(index) {
  return counterTraffic[index].kendaraan
           .map(item => Object.values(item)[0])
           .reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], [])
}
```

And use like this: `let kendaraanNew = getKendaraan(0)`

Can this resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what was expected

```
 const mappedCounterTraffic = counterTraffic.map((item) => {
      const kendaraanNew = Object.entries(item.kendaraan).reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const item = cur[1];
        const newItems = Object.entries(item).reduce((ac, cu) => {
          return [...ac, cu[1]];
        }, []);

        return [...acc, ...newItems];
      }, []);

      console.log("--------", kendaraanNew);

      return {
        ...item,
        kendaraanNew
      };
    });

    console.log(mappedCounterTraffic);
}
```

Response

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "daerah":"Bandung",
      "date":"1668790800000",
      "kendaraan":[
         {
            "rodaEmpat":50
         },
         {
            "rodaDua":22
         },
         {
            "truck":30
         },
         {
            "Bus":70
         }
      ],
      "kendaraanNew":[
         50,
         22,
         30,
         70
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "daerah":"Tasik",
      "date":"1668877200000",
      "kendaraan":[
         {
            "rodaEmpat":80
         },
         {
            "rodaDua":15
         },
         {
            "truck":10
         },
         {
            "Bus":50
         }
      ],
      "kendaraanNew":[
         80,
         15,
         10,
         50
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "daerah":"Bekasi",
      "date":"1669050000000",
      "kendaraan":[
         {
            "rodaEmpat":30
         },
         {
            "rodaDua":65
         },
         {
            "truck":20
         },
         {
            "Bus":100
         }
      ],
      "kendaraanNew":[
         30,
         65,
         20,
         100
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "daerah":"Bandung",
      "date":"1668963600000",
      "kendaraan":[
         {
            "rodaEmpat":20
         },
         {
            "rodaDua":15
         },
         {
            "truck":5
         },
         {
            "Bus":150
         }
      ],
      "kendaraanNew":[
         20,
         15,
         5,
         150
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You want to assign the values of each object of `kendaraan` array in a sperate variable. If Yes, You can simply achieve this by applying the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `kendaraan` array as well inside your `counterTraffic` map.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const counterTraffic = [
  {
    id: 1,
    daerah: "Bandung",
    date:"1668790800000",
    kendaraan: [
      {rodaEmpat: 50},
      {rodaDua: 22},
      {truck: 30},
      {Bus: 70},
    ]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    daerah: "Tasik",
    date:"1668877200000",
    kendaraan: [
      {rodaEmpat: 80},
      {rodaDua: 15},
      {truck: 10},
      {Bus: 50},
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    daerah: "Bekasi",
    date:"1669050000000",
    kendaraan: [
      {rodaEmpat: 30},
      {rodaDua: 65},
      {truck: 20},
      {Bus: 100},
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    daerah: "Bandung",
    date:"1668963600000",
    kendaraan: [
      {rodaEmpat: 20},
      {rodaDua: 15},
      {truck: 5},
      {Bus: 150},
    ]
  }
];

const kendaraanArr = counterTraffic.map(({ kendaraan }) => kendaraan.map(obj => obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]));

const [kendaraan1, ...rest] = kendaraanArr;

console.log(kendaraan1);
```